# Find the closest CCSprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am trying to find the closest "player" to a "ball" and each of these objects are CCSprite Objects. This is my first app, so if there's a better way to do this, feel free to suggest it :)

Here's my code so far:

```
for(CCSprite *currentPlayer in players) {

        // distance formula 
        CGFloat dx = ball.position.x - currentPlayer.position.x;
        CGFloat dy = ball.position.y - currentPlayer.position.y;
        CGFloat distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

        // add the distance to the distances array
        [distances addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:distance]];

        NSLog(@"This happen be 5 times before the breakpoint");
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:distance]);

}
```

So this seems to work well; it logs each distance of the player from the ball. But then when I loop through my "distances" array, like this:

```
for(NSNumber *distance in distances ) {

        NSLog(@"Distance loop");
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:distance]);

}
```

And this is logging a huge number each time, like 220255312. I declare my distances array like this:

```
// setting the distance array
NSMutableArray *distances = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use distance for the @"%@" like this:

```
for(NSNumber *distance in distances ) {

    NSLog(@"Distance loop");
    NSLog(@"%@", distance);

}
```

[NSNumber numberWithInt:distance]

In your first part distance is a CGFloat.

In the second part distance is a NSNumber.

numberWithInt can't take a NSNumber as its argument.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did help! Looks like I had the correct values all along, Cheers Mikey!

Answer (score 0):

```
CCSprite *nearestPlayer;
for(CCSprite *currentPlayer in players) {
    if(nearestPlayer == nil){
        nearestPlayer = currentPlayer;
    }
    if(ccpDistance(ball.position, currentPlayer.position) < ccpDistance(ball.position, nearestPlayer.position)){
        nearestPlayer = currentPlayer;
    }
}
```